# Segmentation Fault (Core Dumped): Error while returning from function

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, return

I have two functions.

```
struct logger_message vget_log_msg(enum LogStatus log_status, const char* format, va_list args) {    
    struct logger_message log_msg;
    log_msg.status = log_status;
    log_msg.timestamp = get_current_timestamp();

    memset(log_msg.message_buffer, 0, MESSAGE_SIZE);
    if(format){    
        vsprintf(log_msg.message_buffer, format, args);
    }
    return log_msg;
}
```

and

```
int send_log_message_to_mqueue(mqd_t mqd, enum LogStatus log_status, const char* format, ...) {
    struct logger_message msg;
    va_list argp;
    va_start(argp, format); 
    msg = vget_log_msg(log_status, format, argp);
    va_end(argp);
    int res; 
    res = send_message_to_mqueue(mqd, (char *)&msg, sizeof(msg));
    return res;
}
```

So, I get the error "Segmentation Fault(Core dumped)" while returning from vget_log_msg on line:

```
msg = vget_log_msg(log_status, format, argp);
```

**EDIT: Maybe this information can be useful**

```
struct logger_message{
    enum LogStatus status;
    time_t timestamp;
    char message_buffer[MESSAGE_SIZE];    
};
```

Does anybody know why I get this error? how to correct it?

Comment: Are you using `-Wall` when compiling? Do you get any warnings?

Comment: Yes, of course. I doesn't get any warnings or erros while compiling the project.

Comment: Is it possible you're `vsprintf()` is walking off the end of your message buffer? If so, have you considered using [`vsnprintf()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/vfprintf) instead? Since you have the buffer size anyway, why not use it. Hopefully your toolchain and runtime are C99 or later compliant, as I believe that was when it first came to us.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is MESSAGE_SIZE? how big is that? Can you check by reducing the size of it, or instead return using pointer instead of the whole structure.

Comment: That's right. The MESSAGE_SIZE, unfortunately, was equal to 24 that was too small. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that you have used `vget_log_msg` without actually declaring its prototype in the file containing `send_log_message_to_mqueue`. for example, by not including the header file that defines `vget_log_msg`, or, if both are in the same file, by not defining `vget_log_msg` before `send_log_message_to_mqueue`.

In that case, the compiler would assume that `vget_log_msg` returns an `int` and not use the correct calling convention for a function returning a struct. Such structs are returned by the caller allocating a buffer for the returned struct on its side of the stack and passing a pointer to that buffer as an implicit parameter to the called function; using the wrong calling convention, then, would cause that implicit pointer to be missing and therefore wrong, and the returning function, then, to write the returned struct to an invalid location.

Alternatively, they could have been made to use different versions of `struct logger_message` by, for instance, including different header files that declare it differently.

Comment: I'm trying to think of any modern compiler (in the last decade or so) that does *not* flag such an assignment from an undeclared function (thereby assuming an `int` return value) as an error when returning anything besides a value that can at least attempt to both hold *and* coerce an `int` to the lvalue being used. Ex: without declaring the function, the OP's code will result in a compilation error stating "error: `struct logger_message` and `int` are incompatible types." While you're point is **very** valid for coercible types from `int` (especially pointers), I'm not sure it is valid here.

Comment: True enough. I've added an alternative explanation.

Comment: No. Any decent compiler would error the hell out you if you try to assign 'int' to a struct.

Comment: The prototype is declarated in header file and the header file is included. So suggestion doesn't work.